# SQLITE cuts off zeros, when updating database

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

Im working with a Sqlite database in C#, when I insert my date into it, everything works fine (in the format `MM.YYYY`). Nevertheless when I update the database, sqlite *cuts off leading zeros*, so `09.2019` appears as `9.2019`. But it's important for further operations that the leading zero remains in it's place.

When creating the table "credits", I use TEXT for the date to store it.

I show you some code how I update the database:

```
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(databaseConnection);

command.CommandText = "Update credits Set lastDate = " + date +
     " WHERE ID=" + Convert.ToString(index);

command.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: add single quotes `command.CommandText = "Update credits Set lastDate = '" + date +
     "' WHERE ID=" + Convert.ToString(index);`

Comment: That is because `09.2019` is a **floating point value** of 9.2019, so yes, it is cut off. You should use parameters and then explicitly specify the type to be DateTime and give a proper DateTime value to avoid mangling of values like this.

Comment: You should store dates as `YYYY-MM-DD` or one of the other formats understood by sqlite [date and time functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html). It'll make things much simpler in the long run.

Comment: Learn to use parameters!  Don't munge query strings with input values.  Then you won't have this problem in the future.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen  sqlite does not have a DateTime type.  Instead, sqlite supports type affinities and will automatically convert data, if possible, to the affine type.  Specifying a column as DateTime actually has a NUMERIC affinity, so it would not have solved the problem in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try *parametrizing* your query; all you should provide is `date` and let RDBMS do its work (formats, representation etc. included)

```
// using - do not forget to Dispose (i.e. free resources)
using (SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(databaseConnection)) {
  // Do not build query, but parametrize it
  command.CommandText = 
     @"update credits 
          set lastDate = @prm_Date
        where ID = @prm_ID";

  // Parameters instead hardcoding
  //TODO: better put command.Parameters.Add(Name, Value, Type)
  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm_Date", date);
  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm_ID", index);

  // Non query : we don't want to return even a single value, right?
  command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```